# Google signin redirecting to google page

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

Hi am developing a app using swift 4 Xcode 9.3.

In my app am integrating google signin.

Everything works fine on my iPhone version 11.3

But when i try to sign in with my iPad version 9.3

It redirects to GOOGLE page.

Help me to solve this one.

Code in my `AppDelegate`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(
            url, 
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)     

    let facebookDidHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)

    return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are making the right calls the open url call you are making is deprecated or changed.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {

        let handled: Bool = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url,  options: options)

        if !handled {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: [:])
        }
        return true
}
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks.Now help me to return for facebook also in same function

Comment: the let handled: Bool  = SDK etc is the Facebook Equivalent... make sure you have the lastest SDK

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your function with this function.your method is depreciate.**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
          let facebookURL = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

           let googleURL = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

        return facebookURL || googleURL   
    }
```

Hope it's helps.!